# c3.js: changing scatterplot radius via another data source?

Tags: javascript, c3.js

From the [example of c3.js](http://c3js.org/samples/chart_scatter.html), a scatterplot is generated by

```
data: {
    x: 'setosa_x',
    columns: [
        ["setosa_x", ...SOME DATA...],
        ["setosa", ...SOME OTHER DATA...],
    ],
    type: 'scatter'
},
```

and google and [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30711843/change-size-of-bubble-in-scatter-plot-for-c3-js) taught me that i can change the radius of bubbles of scatterplot with this manner:

```
point: {
    r: function(d) { // <- d has x, value, and index
        return d.x+d.value+d.index;
    }
}
```

in this way, i can access all information (`x`, `value`, `index`) given the data column has only `x` and `value` data for changing the radius. But I'd like to append additional data for the radius, and access the data via this radius function `r: function(d) {}`. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
var otherData = [17, 11, 4, 8, 12, 34]

var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
            ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
        ],
        type: 'scatter',

    },
    point: {
        r: function(d) { return otherData[d.index]; },
    }
});
```

Comment: though `otherData` is not involved in the c3 structure, this is brilliant. this helps a lot and thanks for the answer.

Comment: +1 @mgraham, here using other dataset we are setting the radius. but how will we scale it for x or y axis - i mean using scale function